# Simple Battleships game implementation in Python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, implementation, 2d-games

Okay I'm not sure how to develop another board with hidden spaces for the computers ships per-se, and have it test for hits. Again I'm not even sure how I'm going to test for hits on the board I have now. Make note: The player turn function will be migrated to the computer board since you wouldn't be attacking your own ships. Here is the code. It may not be the best formatting (as in with Methods and objects and such) but I can polish it up a little later. Also would there be another way to make placing the ships all in one function? Or with the way I have it, will it have to stay that way?

```
class battleship(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.board = [["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ["O"] * 10, ]
    self.printboard()
    self.placeAircraftCarrier()
    self.placeBattleShip()
    self.placeSubmarine()
    self.placeDestroyer()
    self.placePatrolBoat()
    for i in range(100):
         self.playerTurn()


def printboard(self):
    print "Game Board\n"
    print "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
    for row in self.board:
        print "|".join(row)
def placeBattleShip(self):
    while True:
        self.vOrHPlacement = input("Would you like to place the Battleship (1) Vertically or (2)Horizontally?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1 or self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            break
        else:
            print "You must press 1 or 2."
    while True:
        self.battleshipRow = input("With the head as the starting place what row would you like to place the Battleship (Takes 4 Spaces)?:")
        self.battleshipCol = input("What column would you like to start the BattleShip at?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1:
            if self.battleshipRow > 7 or self.battleshipRow <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing vertically you can only choose 1-7 for the row."
            elif self.battleshipCol <= 0 or self.battleshipCol > 10:
                print "You must choose 1 - 10 for a column."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 2
                self.battleshipCol -= 1
                for i in range(4):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow + 1][self.battleshipCol] = "X"
                    self.battleshipRow += 1
                break
        elif self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            if self.battleshipCol > 7 or self.battleshipCol <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing horizontally you can only choose 1-7 for a column."
            elif self.battleshipRow <= 0 or self.battleshipRow > 10:
                print "\n You must choose 1 - 10 as a row choice."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 1
                self.battleshipCol -= 2
                for i in range(4):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow][self.battleshipCol + 1] = "X"
                    self.battleshipCol += 1
                break
    self.printboard()
def placeAircraftCarrier(self):
    while True:
        self.vOrHPlacement = input("Would you like to place the Aircraft Carrier (1) Vertically or (2)Horizontally?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1 or self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            break
        else:
            print "You must press 1 or 2."
    while True:
        self.battleshipRow = input("With the head as the starting place what row would you like to place the Aircraft Carrier (Takes 5 Spaces)?:")
        self.battleshipCol = input("What column would you like to start the Aircraft Carrier at?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1:
            if self.battleshipRow > 6 or self.battleshipRow <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing vertically you can only choose 1-6 for the row."
            elif self.battleshipCol <= 0 or self.battleshipCol > 10:
                print "You must choose 1 - 10 for a column."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 2
                self.battleshipCol -= 1
                for i in range(5):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow + 1][self.battleshipCol] = "X"
                    self.battleshipRow += 1
                break
        elif self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            if self.battleshipCol > 6 or self.battleshipCol <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing horizontally you can only choose 1-6 for a column."
            elif self.battleshipRow <= 0 or self.battleshipRow > 10:
                print "\n You must choose 1 - 10 as a row choice."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 1
                self.battleshipCol -= 2
                for i in range(5):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow][self.battleshipCol + 1] = "X"
                    self.battleshipCol += 1
                break
    self.printboard()
def placeSubmarine(self):
    while True:
        self.vOrHPlacement = input("Would you like to place the Submarine (1) Vertically or (2)Horizontally?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1 or self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            break
        else:
            print "You must press 1 or 2."
    while True:
        self.battleshipRow = input("With the head as the starting place what row would you like to place the Submarine (Takes 3 Spaces)?:")
        self.battleshipCol = input("What column would you like to start the Submarine at?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1:
            if self.battleshipRow > 8 or self.battleshipRow <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing vertically you can only choose 1-8 for the row."
            elif self.battleshipCol <= 0 or self.battleshipCol > 10:
                print "You must choose 1 - 10 for a column."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 2
                self.battleshipCol -= 1
                for i in range(3):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow + 1][self.battleshipCol] = "X"
                    self.battleshipRow += 1
                break
        elif self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            if self.battleshipCol > 8 or self.battleshipCol <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing horizontally you can only choose 1-8 for a column."
            elif self.battleshipRow <= 0 or self.battleshipRow > 10:
                print "\n You must choose 1 - 10 as a row choice."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 1
                self.battleshipCol -= 2
                for i in range(3):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow][self.battleshipCol + 1] = "X"
                    self.battleshipCol += 1
                break
    self.printboard()
def placeDestroyer(self):
    while True:
        self.vOrHPlacement = input("Would you like to place the Destroyer (1) Vertically or (2)Horizontally?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1 or self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            break
        else:
            print "You must press 1 or 2."
    while True:
        self.battleshipRow = input("With the head as the starting place what row would you like to place the Destroyer (Takes 3 Spaces)?:")
        self.battleshipCol = input("What column would you like to start the Destroyer at?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1:
            if self.battleshipRow > 8 or self.battleshipRow <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing vertically you can only choose 1-8 for the row."
            elif self.battleshipCol <= 0 or self.battleshipCol > 10:
                print "You must choose 1 - 10 for a column."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 2
                self.battleshipCol -= 1
                for i in range(3):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow + 1][self.battleshipCol] = "X"
                    self.battleshipRow += 1
                break
        elif self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            if self.battleshipCol > 8 or self.battleshipCol <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing horizontally you can only choose 1-8 for a column."
            elif self.battleshipRow <= 0 or self.battleshipRow > 10:
                print "\n You must choose 1 - 10 as a row choice."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 1
                self.battleshipCol -= 2
                for i in range(3):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow][self.battleshipCol + 1] = "X"
                    self.battleshipCol += 1
                break
    self.printboard()
def placePatrolBoat(self):
    while True:
        self.vOrHPlacement = input("Would you like to place the Patrol Boat (1) Vertically or (2)Horizontally?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1 or self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            break
        else:
            print "You must press 1 or 2."
    while True:
        self.battleshipRow = input("With the head as the starting place what row would you like to place the Patrol Boat (Takes 2 Spaces)?:")
        self.battleshipCol = input("What column would you like to start the Patrol Boat at?:")
        if self.vOrHPlacement == 1:
            if self.battleshipRow > 9 or self.battleshipRow <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing vertically you can only choose 1-9 for the row."
            elif self.battleshipCol <= 0 or self.battleshipCol > 10:
                print "You must choose 1 - 10 for a column."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 2
                self.battleshipCol -= 1
                for i in range(2):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow + 1][self.battleshipCol] = "X"
                    self.battleshipRow += 1
                break
        elif self.vOrHPlacement == 2:
            if self.battleshipCol > 9 or self.battleshipCol <= 0:
                print "\nIf placing horizontally you can only choose 1-9 for a column."
            elif self.battleshipRow <= 0 or self.battleshipRow > 10:
                print "\n You must choose 1 - 10 as a row choice."
            elif self.board[self.battleshipRow - 1][self.battleshipCol - 1] == "X":
                print "There is already a ship there."
            else:
                self.battleshipRow -= 1
                self.battleshipCol -= 2
                for i in range(2):
                    self.board[self.battleshipRow][self.battleshipCol + 1] = "X"
                    self.battleshipCol += 1
                break
    self.printboard()
def playerTurn(self):
    while True:
        self.row = input("What row coordinate would you like to hit?:")
        self.column = input("What column coordinate would you like to hit?")
        if self.row > 10 or self.row < 0:
            print "You must pick a row coordinate between 1 and 10."
        elif self.column > 10 or self.column < 0:
            print "You must pick a column coordinate between 1 and 10."
        elif self.board[self.row - 1][self.column - 1] == "*":
            print "You have already hit there."
        else:
            self.board[self.row - 1][self.column - 1] = "*"
            break
    self.printboard()

b = battleship()
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe I should make the boards objects and the ships objects but I wasn't sure how I could implement them into the game boards. And basically each placeship method is exactly the same with just some slight changes for length of ship.

Comment: Use the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20179953/edit) feature.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot of code organisation. I would suggest keeping Classes free from any sort of looping or inputs! Input stuff from the user & then add that to the class instance, not the other way round. Organize your code & add documentation to it so that others can help you.

You can do some stuff like this

```
class BattleShip:
    """ Ship object container"""

    def __init__(self, position_x, position_y, size):
        """ Necessary variables for the ship go here """
        self.position_x = position_x
        self.position_y = position_y
        self.size = size

    def contains(self, position_x, position_y):
        """ Returns true if supplied point lies inside this ship """
        # code

    def destroy(self, position_x, position_y):
        """ Destroys the ship's point supplied if it contains it """
        assert self.contains(position_x, position_y)
        # Now update the gameboard
        # code

    def isCompletelyDestroyed(self):
        """ Returns True if ship is completely destoryed else False """
        # code


class GameBoard:
    """ The container for the ships """
    def __init__(self, size):
        """Initialize clean GameBoard depending on size, etc """
        self.occupied = "+" # representation for ships
        self.destroyed = 'x' # representation for destroyed area
        self.clear = '-' # representation for clear water

    def printBoard(self):
        """ Print the current gameboard state """

    def update(self, ship):
        """ Updates the gameboard according to updated ship """


# Now do the mainloop
while game_not_over:
    # run game
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Like I said I'm a very amateur programmer only in first semester of CS. I do need to get in the habit of commenting immediately as I write the code. But man are people really harsh about stuff on here. It seems as if some people have sticks shoved up their butts. Sorry just ranting nothing personal. I'm not saying you were harsh because as I reread it I may be reading in between the lines. But anyways. Thank you very much for the suggestions on how to set up the classes. I'm not quite sure how I'll get the completely destroyed part with the board.

Comment: Also Idk how I would check for if the ship is already there or not and how to loop back to the inputs if they add a wrong input (out of index error) without the loop being inside the class. If the objects are set up the way you have them now. I think that check must be in the ship class itself. Or in the methods it contains somewhere..

Comment: For newcomers, it might *seem* like people on StackOverflow are a bit harsh, but trust me, that is NOT the case.

You don't only need to check if 2 ships are same, but also that they DO NOT SHARE ANY POINT. So, I would suggest creating a variable in the board that keeps track of all the occupied points (use [`sets`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) for this)

The board's completely_destroyed method should keep track of number of ships destroyed vs total ships. Call it when a ship is destroyed.

Comment: Don't get discouraged by the downvotes, it's how the system works. Good questions rise to the top & viewed more often than the rest. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: In your theory would GameBoard be a subclass of BattleShip. ugh maybe I need to play around with it more but I'm not sure how to input the ship object into the game board and it actually be read ad a "Variable" Or maybe it's the other way around, Battleship is a subclass of gameboard.

Comment: Depends on how you are comfortable! But, battleship must be a separate class as far as possible. It's instance should give you the points it occupies, so that your gameboard class can then represent those points as a single ship (denoting which points on ship are destroyed & which are not). Hope you get my point.